# Can I retrieve my files which were deleted from the recycle bin too?

Tags: git, github

I committed the changes using git and pushed it to my master branch and then deleted a folder which was named in .gitignore file.
I have tried pulling. I am not able to find that folder.
Is there a way I can get that folder back?

I have been using the atom text editor.
I had integrated git with it and I added the .gitignore file using that text editor itself. Is there a way to retrieve from that atom text editor?

Or is there a way to dig up the deleted files using some recovery software?

Comment: You told git to ignore those files. Why would it know anything about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included your files in your git index before commit git will not keep track of that file changes in the commit. As by default ignored files are not added in git index I guess it is not added to the commit.

In that case, **using Git, you can't**.

But if you are using an IDE which maintains local history (e.g. Any JetBrains IDE, Netbeans etc.) you can get the files from the backup of the IDE.

1. For NetBeans go to [history tab in top of editor](http://wiki.netbeans.org/EditorHistoryTab).
2. For JetBrains IDE (e.g. IntelliJ, WebStorm, PyCharm etc.) Open context menu of the file/folder from project explorer. And Select *Show History* or *Local History* -> *Show History*. [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html)

Comment: I am using atom for python, will that help?

Comment: @YashTibrewal I don't think that Atom stores local history by default. I have found a third party package in github for local history in atom. https://github.com/Nicolab/atom-local-history it may help you to store your future history.